# How to place two divs with an absolute position next to eachother?

Tags: html, css

I cannot place two `<div>`s next to each other because they overlap. I want to have two divs with a separator in the middle of them.

```css
html, body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}


#games {
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}

.game-card, .game-hub-card, .game-card::before, .game-hub-card::before, .game-card::after, .game-hub-card::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.game-card, .game-hub-card {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2rem;
        background-color: #000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.game-card:hover, .game-hub-card:hover {
    &::before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        z-index: -2;
        left: -50%;
        top: -50%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #000;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 0;
        background-image: conic-gradient(transparent, purple, transparent 30%);
        animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
    }
    
    &::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        z-index: -1;
        left: 6px;
        top: 6px;
        width: calc(100% - 12px);
        height: calc(100% - 12px);
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}

.game-list {
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.game-hub-list {
  
}

.game-list, .game-hub-list {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page" id="games">
  <div class="game-list">
    <h3>Games</h3>
    <div class="game-card">
      <img class="game-card-img" src="" alt="Game Icon"></img>
      <h4 class="game-card-title">Coming soon</h4>
      <p class="game-card-description">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="game-type-seperator">
  </div>
  <div class="game-hub-list">
    <h3>Game Hubs</h3>
    <div class="game-hub-card">
      <img class="game-hub-card-img" src="" alt="Game Hub Icon"></img>
      <h4 class="game-hub-card-title">Coming soon</h4>
      <p class="game-hub-card-description">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried `display: inline-block` but that is the issue, and the div's positions HAVE to be absolute.‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: Could you wrap the two divs in a third div and make that element absolute? Then you could use display:inline-block on the inner divs and have them positioned absolutely by their parent.

Comment: The setup is kind of confusing. There is a div that contains the two divs, each of which contains divs with their position set to absolute. @DanielBlack

Comment: It would be good if you explain why the divs need to be absolute positioned. That will help us provide an appropriate solution.

Comment: @vlone is it possible to update the questions with a sample of the issue? It'll make it easier to help (and may be why you're getting the downvotes).

Answer (score 0):

I mean this is just an awkward way of doing this, but if they really need to be positioned absolute then you need to either know and set  the surrounding div's width and calculate the width of the children + position them and/or just have the outer div full width and play with the width, top and left/right values of the children.

Ps. padding counts for the width of the element hence why the `game-list` and `game-hub-list` has the width 236px.

Hope this helps you in the right path!

```css
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

#games {
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

.game-card,
.game-hub-card,
.game-card::before,
.game-hub-card::before,
.game-card::after,
.game-hub-card::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  width: 600px; /* child divs are 300px in width */
}

.game-list {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* positions the div vertically */
  left: 0; /* positions the div horizontally left, this could be in pixels as well ie. left: 50px */
  width: 236px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.game-hub-list {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* positions the div vertically */
  right: 0; /* positions the div horizontally right, this could be in pixels as well ie. left: 50px  */
  width: 236px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.game-card:hover,
.game-hub-card:hover {
  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: -2;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-image: conic-gradient(transparent, purple, transparent 30%);
    animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
  }
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    left: 6px;
    top: 6px;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    height: calc(100% - 12px);
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page" id="games">
  <div class="game-list">
    <h3>Games</h3>
    <div class="game-card">
      <img class="game-card-img" src="" alt="Game Icon"></img>
      <h4 class="game-card-title">Coming soon</h4>
      <p class="game-card-description">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="game-hub-list">
    <h3>Game Hubs</h3>
    <div class="game-hub-card">
      <img class="game-hub-card-img" src="" alt="Game Hub Icon"></img>
      <h4 class="game-hub-card-title">Coming soon</h4>
      <p class="game-hub-card-description">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If an element is `position: absolute`, it will position itself to the closest positioned containing element which is `#games`. Since they both share the same container they are stacked on top of each other. Each card should have `position: relative` so that the `position: absolute` pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after` stay within the `.card` and `card` itself references it's original position instead of `#games`. In the example below, the classNames have been consolidated into simpler forms and details are commented within the source. Also, the OP styles are SCSS and a compiler is needed to convert it into CSS. The example below is simple CSS.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}

#games {
  display: flex /* Makes .menu position themselves in a row */;
  justify-content: center;
  width: max-content;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu {
  min-width: max-content;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

.card {
  position: relative /* Provides a separate reference for pseudo-elements */;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.card:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background: conic-gradient(transparent, purple, transparent 30%);
  animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}

.card:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main id="games" class="page">
  <section id="list" class="menu">
    <h3>Games</h3>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="icon" src="" alt="List Icon">
      <h4 class="title">Coming soon</h4>
      <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="hub" class="menu">
    <h3>Hubs</h3>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="icon" src="" alt="Hub Icon">
      <h4 class="title">Coming soon</h4>
      <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: This appears to work except that the div is so small and you have to scroll within the div. Any workaround to make it cover at least 70% from top to bottom?

Comment: Hi @vlone, are you referring to this demo specifically or on your actual website? If the former, click the  **Full page** link located the top right corner of the demo. If the latter, post the link of the webpage in your next comment.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vlone/2uc7qr9y @zer00ne

Comment: @vlone my demo isn't responsive (since your code has static lengths) so review it as a fullpage. Be aware that the demo has been simplified so it can be easily read so understanding the code is required in order to utilize it -- simply a copy and paste job will not suffice.